# Как правильно прописать в php файле curl запрос POST

Tags: php, post, curl

Как мне правильно написать такой вот запрос в php файле?

```
curl -X POST 'https://a2p-api.megalabs.ru/sms/v1/sms' --header "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"from":"name","to":79995551213,"message":"test"}'  --user login:password
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$auth = base64_encode("mylogin:mypassword");
$headers = array(
'Content-type: application/json',
'Authorization: Basic '.$auth,
);

$data = ['from' => 'SMSCENTER', 'to' => 79261234567, 'message' => 'Test message'];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://a2p-api.megalabs.ru/sms/v1/sms');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Так взлетело.

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = ['form' => 'name', 'to' => 79995551213, 'message' => 'test'];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://a2p-api.megalabs.ru/sms/v1/sms');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type' => 'application/json', 'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode($login . ':' . $password)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Не могу в php файле отправить этот запрос на их сервис по curl. Пишет, что нет доступа к сервису, а когда отправляю этот же запрос
curl -X POST 'https://a2p-api.megalabs.ru/sms/v1/sms' --header "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"from":"name","to":79995551213,"message":"test"}' --user login:password через консоль, то ответ приходит успешным. 

Не могу понять в чем проблема.

Comment: Ок я почитал доки по порталу, сейчас поправлю запрос

Comment: Попробуйте исправленный ответ

Comment: Так же обязательное требование мегафона - авторизация пройдет только с машины, IP которой заявлен для использования сервисом. Так что локально авторизация может не пройти.

Comment: Премного благодарен за информацию и написанный код!

Проверил через Postman и Git bash запросы post уходят и успешный результат приходит. Но когда написанный код curl  сохраняю на php и открываю этот файл по адресу в браузере, то пишет Доступ закрыт. Не могу понять именно в чем дело может быть. Делал с <form method="post" action=""> и ставил проверку if(isset($_POST)) {}, все равно не получается правильно отправить запрос.

Comment: Будьте добры, подскажите пожалуйста, как можно отправить curl post запрос с помощью php через браузер. Или какие альтернативные способы можно применить для того, чтобы отправить смску пользователям.

Comment: curl или же cURL является пакетом  unix то есть такой запрос можно отправить только с сервера. Для отправления SMS обычно используются SMS сервисы, например вот (https://smsc.ru/) вот их API документация - https://smsc.ru/api/

Comment: Поясню про запрос с сервера - это означает прямой запрос без участия браузера, используя сам пакет cURL.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое за информацию! Впервые столкнулся с такой задачей, голову поломал хорошенько)